Unticking all layers in main canvas with PyQGIS
For a plugin, I simply want to untick all the layers in the layer tree. Was thinking of something like :
canvas_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in canvas_layers:
    layer.setVisibility(False)

But there is no such property.
Any idea?

Use the setItemVisibilityChecked() method of the QgsLayerTreeNode class:

Check or uncheck a node (independently of its ancestors or children)

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

